# DataGridView on VB.NET2010

Tags: .net

In datagridview on vb.net 2010, I want to check if a string is in the datagrid, and then if not existing, it will simply add that string.. please help me how.

```
    Dim idTest As String
    cn.Open()
    Try
        sql = "SELECT * from Balance"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read
            idTest = dr.GetString(0)
        End While

        If (??????????????????) Then
            sql = "UPDATE Balance SET [ID Number]= '" & TextBox2.Text & "',[Department Fee Balance]= '" & getDeptFeeBalance() & "',[Total Fines] = '" & getTotalFines() & "'"
            cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Balance Updated", vbOKOnly, "System Information")

        Else
            Dim rs As New OleDbCommand("INSERT into Balance([ID Number],[Department Fee Balance],[Total Fines])values('" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & getDeptFeeBalance() & "','" & getTotalFines() & "')", cn)
            rs.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Balance saved!", vbOKOnly, "System Information")
        End If
        cn.Close()
```

please fill the question mark please

Comment: Please learn to use parameters to avoid sql injection and data formatting errors.  If you only have one row in the Balance table, use `If dr.Read Then` instead of the `While dr.Read` since you aren't looping more than one row.

Comment: my balance table has "ID Number" as a string, balance as double and fines as double.  I'd like to add data if the "ID Number" is not existing, and if it is existing, it will just update. please help me

Comment: please, modify my codes please.

Comment: Your code is pretty broken.  Your sql query should be looking for the balance of the ID Number.  Once you fix that, it would be `If idText <> "" ...`  Money data types should use the decimal data type, not double.

Comment: the connection was not closed. The connections current state is open.

thats the reply, I already placed idText <> "" there, id also did if dr.Read. but it doesnt work also. can you modify the whole code ? please?

Comment: Like I said, learn to use parameters.  `SELECT * from Balance WHERE [ID Number] = ?`.   Then you need `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)`  Try closing your connection after you use it once, then open it again for the next command, close it again, etc.

Comment: okay. ill try . thank you for the info. This will  help. Sorry to disturb

Comment: You can also combine INSERT and UPDATE into MERGE